# /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied while running docker within Python CGI script

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am trying to run Python CGI script inside which I need to run docker image.
I am using Docker version 1.6.2. user is "www-data", which is added in docker group.

```
www-data : www-data sudo docker
```

On machine, with www-data I am able to execute docker commands

```
www-data@mytest:~/html/new$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

I am getting following error while running docker image from Python CGI script:

```
fatal msg="Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/images/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?"
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Permission denied on a default install indicates you are trying to access the socket from a user other than root or that is not in the docker group. You should be able to run:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $username
```

on your desired $username to add them to the group. You'll need to logout and back in for this to take effect (use `newgrp docker` in an existing shell, or restart the daemon if this is an external service accessing docker like your cgi scripts).

Note that doing this effectively gives that user full root access on your host, so do this with care.

Comment: Thanks! That helped in resolving the issue.

Comment: Restarting your machine might also help to take effect the changes.

Comment: I had to run `sudo chgrp docker /var/run/docker.sock`, too.

Comment: @Milanka if that happens on an install from the docker repos, there's something broken.

Comment: @BMitch I restart docker service as above comment, but error is still: `Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.37/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
`

Comment: @BenyaminJafari did you log out and back in? The comment on restarting the service was about other daemons connecting to docker, I've removed it to avoid confusion.

Comment: @BMitch I can't restart, because it is a server!

Comment: It turns out I must restart my PC to take effect. But I still do not know why. Before restarting my PC, I cannot see docker group in the output of command `id`.

Comment: Adding the group and rebooting the machine did not help me on docker `17.06.2-ce` with kernel `4.19.11-1` on a CentOS 7 EC2 instance. I had to specifically assign permissions by setting ACLs `setfacl -m ec2-user:6 /var/run/docker.sock`