# How to remove dangling images in Docker

Tags: docker

How can I remove dangling Docker images? I tried

```
sudo docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```

but it shows

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon
>   socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get
>   http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.35/images/json?filters=%7B%22dangling%22%3A%7B%22true%22%3Atrue%7D%7D:
>   dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/var/run/docker.sock: permission denied while running docker within Python CGI script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877705/var-run-docker-sock-permission-denied-while-running-docker-within-python-cgi-s)

Answer (score 65):

Recent docker has added the [`image prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) command so this task only requires a single invocation of docker

```
sudo docker image prune
```

For the `sudo` problem, both `docker` commands require `sudo` otherwise the `docker images` list will run first as your user.

```
sudo docker rmi $(sudo docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```

Sometimes `sudo` doesn't work properly when run like this for the `docker images` query and you need to run the entire command under a single `sudo`:

```
sudo sh -c 'docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)'
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay.. but when i used your command it shows like " Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 6ce3b43f032e (must be forced) - image is being used by stopped container 90e1830602a0"

Comment: There's a container that has `exited` running the image `docker ps -a`. As it says, remove the container  then you can remove the image

Comment: I solved the issue.. just modified the command like " sudo sh -c 'docker rmi -f $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)'"   it worked..thank you.

Answer (score 33):

Docker has a build-in command to cleanup dangling images.

```
sudo docker image prune
```

To cleanup unused images and dangling ones, use:

```
sudo docker image prune -a
```

Comment: wrong answer… `-a, --all             Remove all unused images, not just dangling ones`

Comment: Updated the answer, made the distinction between removing unused images and just dangling ones.

Comment: I think you are confusing **[docker image prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/)** with **[docker system prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)**. The docker documentation clearly states that **docker image prune** will only do the following `Remove all dangling images. If -a is specified, will also remove all images not referenced by any container.`

Comment: it will also remove unused images.

Comment: And this destructive option `-a` is what OpenAI chatbots are now recommending for cleaning dangling images... it should never be put in the answer to the question about the removal dangling images alone

Answer (score 8):

To make it work without `sudo`

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly the same as the top-voted answer?

Comment: Assuming that this works without root, I think the lack of `sudo` makes this a different answer.

Answer (score 5):

Simply do

```sh
docker image prune
```

It will ask you to confirm

```
WARNING! This will remove all dangling images.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N]
```

Type `y`, you're done... Or use `-f` to not prompt for confirmation.

```sh
docker image prune -f
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Matt mentioned, you are missing `sudo` in inner command. Below will work

```
sudo docker rmi $(sudo docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```

To get rid of using `sudo` everytime, give `docker` user permissions. Follow below steps

1. Create the docker group.

   ```
   $ sudo groupadd docker
   ```
2. Add your user to the docker group.

   ```
   $ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
   ```